# how the get input like (X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :) in scheme

Tags: input, scheme, racket

I'm trying to get this input in scheme. But ı do not get second part. How can i get this part ? -> (X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :)

```
('stack (X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "get" the way I think you do, you can just do:

```
> (define a '('stack (X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :)))
> (cadr a)
(X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :)
```

The procedure "cadr" gives you the second element in a list. You can also do:

```
> (car (cdr a))
(X p c F z C b Y h 1 2 3 4 : :)
```

If this is not what you mean, you will have to provide more details in your question because it is too unclear.